crocoblock jet engine meta field value based on other field
created a  crocoblock custom post type meta field start-date, which is Date type field and their is another field called Month, where i want to store the month value  of start-date. like
start-date = 11/05/1979
month = 05
we tried  dynamic field widget which does this but it works in font end, we want to store this value in the field.
is their any filter or hook for this in crocoblock jet engine?
